# Customizing Spring Initializr

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot, initializr

I am working on bringing up a new team in the Spring Boot ecosystem. I love the Spring Initializr service. We have written custom Gradle plugins for unifying our build systems across many Spring Boot projects. I am looking to provide our team with an Initializr that will take advantage of our build tooling as well as inject some of our business practices into the scaffolding of the project.

With these goals in mind we have decided that extending the wonderful Spring Initializr and running a custom instance locally makes a lot of sense.

Unfortunately, it appears that the Initializr project has very little documentation about customizing it, beyond the basics of editing the YAML configuration and the Templates for the java files, it is difficult (for someone with no Groovy Templating experience) to figure out how to best extend the Initializr such that we maintain much of the functionality but can also extend the site and service appropriately.

We have built the github project from source, and published the artifacts to our local artifactory, and have successfully created our own project that uses those artifacts as a dependency and stands up a mildly customized service (basic HTML and Java source editing, simple YAML configuration).

Can anyone help with even basic resources for extending the functionality of the Initializr? perhaps a roadmap? a project specific forum? really any help is appreciated, my google-foo seems to be failing me.

I know this is a reasonably broad question, but I am failing to get in touch with the right people, or find the resources for this.

Comment: You can chat with the Initializr team [on Gitter](https://gitter.im/spring-io/initializr).

Comment: Thanks @AndyWilkinson I will certainly do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is indeed Gitter. Spring Initializr should be seen at the moment as a service and not a library. We do our best to make sure things are nicely separated but that's not the case yet for everything (read: designed for extension).

We have some plans to allow external components to customize how the project is generated. It would help if you could share your use cases on the gitter channel. Thanks!